# iTunes connect spamming error emails to users

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Every time we upload an app with an issue (missing entitlement, privacy string missing from the project's .plist), iTunes connect emails the error to *every* single one of the tester emails in our list, *even* if they're not registered to test for the application I am uploading.

Currently I am the only person in the list for this application, and yet it's sending the email to everyone testing an unrelated app.

How do I turn this ridiculous behavior off and stop annoying them?

Comment: This is a question to ask of Apple support, not stack overflow.

Comment: Given there are questions on Stack Overflow about configuring and troubleshooting Xcode, I am unclear where the delineation is between that and iTunes connect?

Comment: The difference here is that you are reporting a bug about Apple's website. Let Apple know. No one here can possibly help.

Comment: Then surely, just answer "This is not the behaviour I see, file this as a bug.", given I assumed this was a 'hidden' default, rather than a bug... As I would have thought the question implied?

Comment: Its actually helpful especially if another developer experiences the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* a bug.  It is a 'feature' of PEBKAB.

The issue was another developer had quietly added the users to itunes connect as internal testers on a separate project.  They had all been given a 'developer' role, and when I created the app, they were automatically put on the developer email list for that one, too.

A quick diddle of the users and roles table fixed it all up, no trip to Apple Support required.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is just how iTunes Connect works. I have reached Apple complaining about this, their answer was that I should use External TestFlight distributions.

Honestly I really recommend you to use other beta distribution platform like beta by Fabric, the build process is using ad-hoc builds, in our team we use beta by Fabric for small builds then once we are almost ready to push to the AppStore we run a small test by using the final build in TestFlight.

I'm not saying Testflight External distributions are bad but is not the right tool for a daily workflow some times you can't afford waste 3 to 6 hours waiting for apple to approve your new build.

Comment: Yeah, it's a real pain.  Those 'developer' accounts had been added precisely to have a fast turnaround on another project (the client demands tight weekly release deadlines). Thanks for the suggestion, I will check that out!